# FBSession often fails to be at FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded when returning to foreground

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK3.0 (client is not ready to move to 3.1 yet), and have been having trouble to get FBSession to be at the FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded when the app returns to the foreground after a longer period of time (close to a day); I don't have issue if I just send the app to background and come back to the foreground after a minute or two

my code is as follow, please let me know if I should provide further information; I have this issues across devices (4, 4S, 5) and iOS version (4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...   
  if (![self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
    // still allow loading the public feed even though user is not logged in (the view controller will have a login button overlay)
    [[self pictureFeedVC] loadFeed];
  }
  ...
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  DEBUGLog(@"didBecomeActive");
  DEBUGLog(@"FBSession is Open? %@",FBSession.activeSession.isOpen ? @"YES" : @"NO");

  if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) {
    //Dismiss login view controller
    if ([self.tabBarController modalViewController]) {
        [self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
  }
}

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
  BOOL result = NO;

  [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorSessionStateTransitions,nil]];
  NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", @"email", nil];

  FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil permissions:permissions urlSchemeSuffix:FB_URL_SCHEME_SUFFIX tokenCacheStrategy:nil];

  if (allowLoginUI || (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)) {
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
    result = session.isOpen;
  }
  return result;
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
  DEBUGLog(@"changed FB state");
  switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
      if (!error) {
        DEBUGLog(@"FBSessionStateOpen");
        [[self pictureFeedVC] loadFeed];
      }
    break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
      DEBUGLog(@"FBSessionStateClosed");
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
      DEBUGLog(@"FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed");
      [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
      [self.tabBarController showFBLoginView];
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
}
```

I am having problem where after extended period in the background, the `DEBUGLog(@"FBSession is Open? %@",FBSession.activeSession.isOpen ? @"YES" : @"NO");` in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` will print a `NO`

more info: this app relies on Facebook login entirely, it uses facebook user ID to identify users, therefore for lots of actions I need to pass the Facebook access token so that the server can get the facebook user ID even though a lot of times those actions does not require api calls to facebook (besides getting the user ID from the access token of course). My other question is whether I need to actively do something to refresh the token or do something keep the FBSession open (if so, how?), would that be the reason why the `FBSession.activeSession` might not be in an open state when I return to foreground?

Thanks much in advance!